# Can we send HTML emails using PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have been working on a email script and it works. Prob is I do it using a textarea . can I send an HTML email?if so , how?
**Edit**: Found the answer

Comment: Oh thanks found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can. You have to set headers for that

```
$to = 'abc@example.com';
$subject = 'My Subject';
$message='<b>test</b>';

$headers = "From: test@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: test@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: test2@test.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```